# Issue in connecting to bot service via Directline channel

Tags: chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I have the integrated "botframework-webchat" package for my web chat panel, I'm generating token using directline secret and creating direcline object using it. Note: I have grped the directline secret from Azure Bot Service in the directline channel.

In my react app, I'm using "ReactWebChat" component from "botframework-webchat" and passing directline object to it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from "botframework-webchat";
import "./webchat.css";
import { StyleOptions } from "botframework-webchat/lib/index-minimal";
import { FlexBox, Icon, Title } from "@ui5/webcomponents-react";
import "@ui5/webcomponents-icons/dist/arrow-left.js";
import { ReactComponent as BotButton } from "./assets/bot_button.svg";
import { ReactComponent as BotLogo } from "./assets/bot_logo.svg";

export default function WebChat() {
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);
  const [directLine, setDirectLine] = useState<any>();
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");

  useMemo(async () => {
    if(token) {
    setDirectLine(createDirectLine({ token }));    
    }
  }, [token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      const tokenObj = window.sessionStorage.getItem("directlineToken");
      if (tokenObj === null) {     
        const res = await fetch(
          "https://commandb.azurewebsites.net/api/config"
        );
        const { token } = await res.json();
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("directlineToken", token);     
        setToken(token);
      } else {
        setToken(tokenObj);
      }
    };
    getToken();
  }, []);
```

```
   <ReactWebChat
            directLine={directLine}
            role="main"
            className={"webchatMain"}
            styleOptions={styleOptions}
          />

/* I'm using it like this*/
```

Directline object connection status should be changed to "Online". In my case it always showing "Connecting".

Comment: I don't see anything that is jumping out as wrong. Have you tried setting breakpoints and stepping thru while debugging to see what is happening? You could also compare your code to the code provided in some of the React samples provided in the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo. Lastly, be sure the Always On configuration settings in your bot's Azure app service is enabled. That will also have an affect, but usually only after a period of inactivity.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Thank you very much for your response. The issue lies with the initial render in React. In my case, it was rendering twice, creating tokens twice, and initializing the DirectLine object twice. Consequently, the latest instance is unable to connect to the DirectLine. I resolved this problem by decoupling my parent and child components.